# A word to describe the act to switch between positive and negative?

Tags: single-word-requests, descriptive-grammar

I am doing some programming with math. I have written a tidy function which turns any positive number to negative or any negative number to a positive.

I would like to name this function in the most informative way so that if someone else were to look at my function; they would understand, straight away, what it does (and expect what it says on the tin).

The best word I can come up with is 'flip' but I feel that it fails at being obvious.

The function belongs to the Math object so it looks like this:

```
answer = Math.flip(number)
```

The results might be

```
-1 = Math.flip(1)
```

or

```
1 = Math.flip(-1)
```

How can I best describe this act?

Comment: My calculator uses ***CHS*** ( change sign).

Comment: Most if not all programming languages don't have a name for this function because it is achieved by simple use of the minus sign: 1 = - (-1). I hope you aren't really having to write a function that does that.

Comment: What @Avon said. But if you really wanted to implement such a function, ***negate*** would surely be a natural name for it. negate(-1) returns +1, obviously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers negate's good but it has, sort of 'nullify' connotations to me. How about minus(1)?

Comment: Interestingly, x *= -1; is regarded on stackoverflow as the best way to do it in Java (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869911/java-math-function-to-convert-positive-int-to-negative-and-negative-to-positive). Horrifyingly, x = x * -1 is regarded as the best way in C# (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348080/convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-c-sharp) and x = System.Math.Abs(x) * (-1); comes in second. I think people might have been poking fun there.

Comment: Negate.  Invert.  Change polarity (electrical).  Toggle.  Switch.

Comment: @Avon - NEG for negate in ARM assembly language.  *Invert* tends to mean one bit rather than a number, but it works too.

Comment: Math.flip=function(n){return ~n+1;}

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are programming languages not 'off topic', in as much as they are not the English language?

Comment: @WS2: Sure - when the *only* reason anyone would seek a name for an action is if they needed to name a function than performs said function within their program. But in this case there are many other contexts where one might reasonably want to use a word meaning *reverse the sign of [some positive/negative value]*. I for example distinguish between commenting that I've *canceled* or *reversed* a downvote here on ELU in response to an edit *(cancel = retract, reverse = replace by an **upvote**)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[invert](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invert)**

> verb
>   1.3 chiefly Mathematics Subject to inversion; transform into its inverse.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

but it has lots of meanings in maths. More precisely, it is the [Additive Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse)

> the additive inverse of a number a is the number that, when added to
>   a, yields zero

and not to be confused with [Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse)

> a multiplicative inverse or reciprocal for a number x, denoted by 1/x
>   or x<sup>−1</sup>, is a number which when multiplied by x yields the
>   multiplicative identity, 1

(wikipedia)

So... err... invert additively? It's not very good, sorry.

Comment: invert is good!